# Best practices for client side vs. server side redirects: When to use what?

Tags: redirect, client, webserver

I understand that most of the languages support server side redirects `(asp.net: Response.Redirect, PHP: header( 'newpage' ) ; )`. You could also do a redirect with JavaScript `(window.location.href="newLocationURL")`.

When would you choose one over the other ?

With respect to ASP.net/IIS7(app pool in Integrated mode,enable 32 bit apps=false), I noticed that even when the page has a 302 header, the whole page body is sent to the client side.

And [I believe this is not the case with PHP](http://www.satya-weblog.com/2009/10/php-redirect-vs-javascript-redirect.html), only headers are sent ? To quote
Redirect on client side means following steps:Client-side -> Server-side -> Client-side -> Server-side -> Client-side.

Redirect on Server-Side means:Client-side -> Server-side -> Client-side (headers only)* -> Server-side -> Client-side.

Is there a W3C standard  or  server side redirect implementation differ from one web server technology to another ?

Edit: I am only concerned about Response.Redirect (in asp.net) and not server.transfer, at least for this discussion

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The JavaScript example is actually not a **redirect**. There's no means of a [301/302](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.2) response. It is just a simple request which happens during a certain Javascript event long time after the page is arrived. If you do this during page load, then it would have more overhead than a real redirect and it would not work on JS-disabled browsers as well.

Redirects are to be initiated from the server side with a 301/302 response. All webapp languages/frameworks defaults to 302. You can usually make it 301 by adding one extra parameter or code line which instructs that. The benefit of 301 is by the way that the particular request won't be indexed (anymore) by the searchbots.

Answer (score 6):

In ASP.Net, there is an important distinction between two kinds of server-side redirects. They are Response.Redirect and Server.Transfer.

If you call **Response.Redirect**, that entails two round trips to the server. On the first call to the server, the server response directs the browser to request the next page. Requesting that next page constitutes the second round trip to the web server.

If you use **Server.Transfer**, there is only one round trip. Therefore, there is much less network traffic. However, there is a limitation to using Server.Transfer, which is that the target page has to be on the same web server. That is, you can't Server.Transfer from your web app to www.Google.com. But you can Response.Redirect to it.

There are other details involved with using either of these approaches which you would want to research before using them. However, I believe that it is significant in the context of this question to note that in any language, **Response.Redirect may result in much heavier network traffic than is really necessary.**

Comment: your response is appreciated. Server.Transfer does not send a 302 unlike Response.Redirect. Sorry I was not clear with my question

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on where you decide that you need to redirect. If it is server side code that determines that you have to redirect, then it is server side code that issues the redirect command. If you can decide client side that a redirect is needed, then do it from the client code.

It is probably more efficient from client side, since you avoid a the back-and-forth of the server side redirect thing..

Comment: If it is server side code that determines that you have to redirect what prevents the server side code from adding a javascript code, telling the client to redirect ?

Comment: Nothing - you can do that if you like, but calling Response.Redirect is, to me, easier than generating the javascript to set window.location.href. And the response to the browser should be a little smaller. PS - in my experience, asp.net *does not* send the entire page content with a Response.Redirect - it only sends the necessary headers and the small amount of html for the standard "object moved to" message (which rarely gets used).

Comment: Yup Ray, I was surprised to see that in Charles. It happens for Cassini as well as IIS7-integrated mode, though not checked with other server/server configurations

Comment: Charles? When you say 'the whole page body was sent' do you mean all of your text/form fields/images/etc?

Comment: Yup. Charles debugging proxy. And the response includes any text I add in a HttpModule-EndRequest

Comment: Never heard of Charles before - looks cool - like Fiddler. Anyway, in Fiddler I see none of that stuff after my Response.Redirect. I have constructed my pages so that none of the content creation is done if I am going to redirect, so the response to the browser is minimal.